# Listing layers from .mxd file using ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro, mxd

I am looking for a way to access a .mxd file's layer names and data sources.

In ArcGIS Desktop, I could do:

```
def print_layer_info(mxd_path):
    print(mxd_path + ":")
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)

    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*"):
        lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)[0]
        if lyr.supports("dataSource"):
            print "\t" + lyr.name
            print "\t\t" + lyr.dataSource
    del mxd
```

According to http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm, I could do:

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("file.mxd")
```

But that doesn't work. When I do that I get a OSError.

Since the arcpy.mapping.MapDocument is gone in ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro, what is the equivalent way of reading layer name and datasource of an .mxd file?

Answer (score 3):

You can list the layers and the datasources of an MXD (ArcMap document) from **ArcGIS Pro** by simply importing the MXD into a project, and then following the same workflow you would do from ArcMap. (The syntax may vary a little).

- Load up a project (like `current`, as the following code is run from the Python window)
- Load the MXD into it
- Find the map
- List the layers

code:

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
p.importDocument(r"C:\data\data.mxd")
for m in p.listMaps(): print(m.name)
> Layers
mxd = p.listMaps("Layers")[0]
for l in mxd.listLayers():
    if l.supports("dataSource"):
        print("{}, {}".format(l.name, l.dataSource))
> World Ocean Reference, 
> foo1, source1
> foo2, source2
> World Ocean Base,
```

Comment: I was asking for a ArcPy-only solution. I need to process thousands of mxds, so I don't want to manually open ArcGIS Pro and then do an import for every single MXD.

Comment: This is an arcpy only solution. If you mean you want to run the code entirely _outside_ ArcGIS Pro, then make 1 dummy/template Project, reference that instead of `current` and just import MXDs into that. Since there is no map "remove" option from the project class, trash your `p` reference for each run and re-establish it, thus importing into a "new-blank" project.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the `arcpy.mp` module that comes with ArcGIS Pro to create a `MapDocument` object from an `*.mxd`.

To do that you use `arcpy.mapping` from the `arcpy` site-package that comes with the ArcGIS Desktop 10.x architecture and works against the ArcMap application.

To work with the content of an `*.mxd` in ArcGIS Pro (or the `arcpy` which it installs) you would first need to import the `*.mxd` into an ArcGIS Pro project (and then create `ArcGISProject` and `Map` objects from that).

Comment: Can I programmatically create a ArcGIS Pro project or would I have to manually do it? Ultimately, I'm writing a script to automate over many .mxd files.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  That should be asked as a new question.

Comment: I would also like to know if there's a way to create a virtual ArcGIS Pro Project using arcpy. I am only interested in being able to read information about layers in an .mxd

Comment: What do you mean by a "virtual ArcGIS Pro Project"?  In any event it sounds like you may need to ask a new question about that.