# Extracting map properties (extent, metadata, coordinate system, transformation) using arcpy.mp?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am trying to fetch map properties using arcpy.mp (since I am using ArcGIS Pro trial version) from mxd files.

I am able to get the extent info for individual layers but not for the dataframe. Sample code

```
fc = "\demo.gdb\dist"
spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference
print("Co ordinate : ", spatial_ref.name)
extent = arcpy.Describe(fc).extent
```

There are code samples available with arcpy.mapping module (for desktop vsersion), but I am using ArcGIS Pro, which supports arcpy.mp module.

Comment: Please add your code to avoid closing your question.

Comment: [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/311277/115) to the duplicate shows you code samples for getting at map properties in an MXD using arcpy.mp.  If there is a particular map property you are stuck on then please provide a code snippet that uses arcpy.mp to try and get at it.